# Conmigo vs. Comigo

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones, ortografía, español-neutral, portugués

There is a song *«Baila, baila comigo»* by the [Dominó](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domin%C3%B3) band from Brazil. I paid attention that in some places it's written `conmigo` while in another — `comigo`. Could you, please, explain me what's the difference? Is it Spanish vs. Portuguese version of the same word?

A bonus question: [Baïla vs. Baila](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5793/ba%C3%AFla-vs-baila).

Comment: I have no idea why the *ï* would be used.  At best it would be used if the song pronounced it BA-i-la (dieresis is used in poetry to mark un stressed hiatuses), but that's definitely very non-standard and unexpected for both Spanish and Portuguese.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the context (a song in Portuguese sung by a Brazilian group), I would assume that when written `conmigo` it's indeed a Spanish version of the song; and when written `comigo` is a Portuguese (original) version of the song (keeping in mind, of course, that `baila` is written in the same way in Spanish and in Portuguese).

---

Although, here's a fun fact regarding the use of `comigo` and `conmigo`: `comigo` is a word that does exist in Spanish, **although it's quite old and is no longer used**.

The [Diccionario de la Lengua Española](https://dle.rae.es/?id=9w9Db9d) has an entry for `comigo`:

> **1.** pron. person. 1.ª pers. m. y f. sing. desus. conmigo.

As you may notice, the Dictionary states that it's a word that's **no longer used**. Even in a dictionary from 1729 (Autoridades), the entry states that the **word is antiquated**:

> **Comigo**: adv. Lo mismo que Conmigo. Es voz antiquada [...].

Comment: Thanks a lot. I elaborated the question, added `Baila` vs. `Baïla`.

Comment: @MikeB. I think you should better ask that question (regarding baila) in the Portuguese Language Stack Exchange. I bet there's someone with an answer there